# f.autocomplete_field :tag_list in an edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

This is for an **edit form** of an **existing photo** with **existing tags** (tag_list). I am using the actsastaggable gem.

```
<%= simple_form_for @photo do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, 'Tags (seperated by commas):', class: 'label-tags'%>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ', 'data-auto-focus' => true, :id_element => '#tag_element', class: 'photo-edit-2' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update'%>   
<% end %>
```

So if a User **edits** a photo with the **existing** tag_list of `sunday, dog, soda` it is showing up in the input as `sunday dog soda` **without any commas separating the tags**. I need it to show up with commas separating the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code as follows:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_photos_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ', 'data-auto-focus' => true, :id_element => '#tag_element', class: 'photo-edit-2', :value => @photo.tags.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

The problem was that the default value was being set to the value of tag_list an array, but was ignoring commas. We use the map method to grab the tags by name and then use the join method to place commas in-between each name.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)